# How to stop Sphinx Speech Recognition

Tags: android, google-glass, cmusphinx

I'm currently writing an application for Google Glass that recognizes certain words. I'm using pocket sphinx for android (http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/), and it runs okay on Glass, however, it doesn't open as a regular application but rather in the background. (I am okay with this, but if anyone has suggestions on how to make it an app that I can open with "ok Glass" I'd appreciate it!)

My problem is, because it runs automatically and continuously, I don't know how to stop it! I want to be able to tap the side of Glass and have it stop or something, but because it's not an application, it does not allow me to do this. Can someone point me in the right direction to solve this?

I'm new to developing for Android and Glass, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: You do know that Google have withdrawn Glass?

Comment: For the time being, but they're getting ready to release it again :)